# How do I rollback to a specific git commit

Tags: git, rollback

I have rolled back already using this command `git reset --hard HEAD^` to some previous commit, all I want to do is rollforward I know this isn't the correct term to what would be my commit that I did latest. Whats happening is a bunch of files were deleted when I used that command and now I don't know how to get back. I am using github is there a way to just pull down from github and overwrite the current directory?

Comment: Just an FYI: if all you really wanted to do is explore your history, you could've checked out the version that you're interested in with `git checkout HEAD^`.  That would put your working tree in a detached HEAD state, but allow you to examine history without changing what your branch is pointing to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your question, the commit you want to retrieve is the current one on the `master` branch of the GitHub repo, you have to do the following

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

WARNING this will erase all uncommitted modifications that you could have made since you rolled back on `HEAD^`.

Before, you might want to do

```
git fetch origin
```

To make sure you've got the latest changes from the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `git reflog`. Among its output you should find the commit you want to reset to. Then `git reset --hard` to it and you're back where you were before your first `reset`.

`git reflog` is especially useful if you really screw your local repository up and don't have a remote repository you can use to pull commits from. It should work fine as long as you haven't called `git prune` to get rid of old commits or `git reflog expire` to clean the reflog.