# How do you set a tutorial project to a specific git commit state?

Tags: git, github

I want to set my project to this state:

https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/commit/3140d32eb1cfa1cbca28a84ef3626b7d93cca569

I have cloned the whole project. Then i try:

```
git checkout 3140d32eb1cfa1cbca28a84ef3626b7d93cca569
fatal: reference is not a tree: 3140d32eb1cfa1cbca28a84ef3626b7d93cca569
```

I've also tried

```
git reset --hard 3140d32eb1cfa1cbca28a84ef3626b7d93cca569
Could not parse object '3140d32eb1cfa1cbca28a84ef3626b7d93cca569
```

I have read these questions.

[How do I rollback to a specific git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703095/how-do-i-rollback-to-a-specific-git-commit)

[How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset)

Comment: Try `git checkout 3140d32eb`

Comment: Looking at the commit history, I don't see any such commit: https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/commits/master So, the commit might've been reverted/rebased/overwritten!

Comment: Then this happens:

$ git checkout 3140d32eb
error: pathspec '3140d32eb' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: How did you clone the project?  If I clone that repository, `git checkout 3140d32eb1cfa1cbca28a84ef3626b7d93cca569` works for me.

Comment: git clone git@github.com:DiscoverMeteor/Microscope.git

Comment: Can you show me the steps that worked for you @torek?

Comment: I did: `cd <place>; git clone git://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope; cd Microscope; git checkout 3140d32eb1cfa1cbca28a84ef3626b7d93cca569`.  (http:// should produce the same result, I just prefer to use git:// when possible)

Comment: Beginner misstake. Was in the wrong directory.